# c++ invalid covariant return type with pointer

Tags: c++, oop, g++

I already searched a lot to find a solution for my problem, but I can't find a way to get the following code to work.

**Background**

I wrote a class structure that represents any kind of Archive (in my real case, this would be a FileRepository which also might be an Archive). Therefore I defined a pure virtual class structure representing an archive.

An archive is actually a directory, a directory is actually an entity (Base in this case). A file within this archive also would be an entity (Base). These classes are used as interface for real implementations.

In the code you'll see the My... implementations of these classes.

**Problem**

The MyDirectory implementation overwrites the Base's *getParent* method which expects a Directory to be returned. Actually, the MyDirectory implementation only can have a MyDirectory as parent, therefor the new implementation returns a MyDirectory, not a Directory. That's where C++ throws the error message!

The compiler doesn't know, that MyDirectory actually **is** a Directory, because I overwrite the *getParent* method in the MyBase class, before declaring the MyDirectory class.

And as MyDirectory also wants to call specific MyDirectory methods (as getAbsolutePath), I really need the return type to be MyDirectory, not Directory. (and static_cast did not work, either :()

I would be happy about any hint, how to solve my problem :)

**Edit: Details**

The problem actually is the complicated inheritance graph. The problem is that MyDirectory inherits MyBase, but MyBase's method returns MyDirectory - but the Base class requires to return a Directory, but at declaration, c++ does not know that MyDirectory actually is a Directory. I'm trying to solve, that MyDirectory can return a MyDirectory instance and does not require to return a Directory instance.

```c
// Just an example code - actually is separated in .h and .cpp and cleaner and and and... :)

class Directory;
class MyDirectory;

class Base {
public:
    /// Returns the parent directory
    virtual Directory *getParent()=0;
};

class Directory : virtual public Base {
public:
};

class Archive : virtual public Directory {
public:
};

// ---------------------------------

class MyBase : virtual public Base {
public:
    /// Constructor
    MyBase(int i, int j, int k) {}

    /// Returns the parent directory
    MyDirectory *getParent() { return NULL; }

    /// Returns the parent directory
    virtual const char *getAbsolutePath() const { return "my full path"; }
};

class MyDirectory : virtual public Directory, public MyBase {
public:
    /// Constructor
    MyDirectory(int i, int j) : MyBase(i, j, i+j) {}

    /// Returns the parent directory (not really, I know! Just an example)
    virtual const char *getAbsolutePath() const { return getParent()->getAbsolutePath(); }
};

class MyArchive : virtual public Archive, public MyDirectory {
public:
    /// Constructor
    MyArchive(int i) : MyDirectory(i, i) {}
};
```

Comment: What line is the error?

Comment: You must fully define the types before using them as covariant return types.

Comment: This isn't an example of covariant return types. It would be if the return types were `Base` and `MyBase`. Now they are just unrelated types and that doesn't work - just like you have noticed.

Comment: Also, what's the problem you're trying to solve? Adding this insanely complicated inheritance graph seems pointless.

Comment: The problem actually is the complicated inheritance graph. The problem is that MyDirectory inherits MyBase, but MyBase's method returns MyDirectory - but the Base class requires to return a Directory, but at declaration, c++ does not know that MyDirectory actually is a Directory. I'm trying to solve, that MyDirectory can return a MyDirectory instance and does not require to return a Directory instance. The error occures on the "MyDirectory *getParent()" line.

Comment: well uhm, RTTI is out of talk here? basicly always return base class and downcast to the fitting derived level

Comment: @BenjaminSchulte: you nailed the issue, the inheritance graph **is** too complicated for its own good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Covariant return types are just convienience.

Write `GetMyParent()` that returns `MyDirectory`.  Defer the implementation of `GetParent` and `GeyMyParent` until `MyDirectory` is visible, then have `GetParent` call `GetMyParent`.

In `MyDirectory` you could make `GetParent` fully covarient if you want to, but I wouldn't bother.  Never override `GetParent` after `MyBase`, if that is needed override `GetMyParent` instead.

Maybe make `GetParent` private so you do not accidentally call it.  If you have a `MyBase`, call `GeyMyParent` instead.

If this makes code annoying to maintain, write a free function calped `GetParent` that uses overrides to pick which one to call.  If you hate free functions, add a non virtual method that picks which one to call (well two, one in `Base` and one in `MyBase`).

The only problem with the free function/non-virtual method is that your multi-path tree can confuse it, resulting in ambiguity.  I would just go with calling `GetMyParent()` when you know have a `MyBase` and need a `MyDirectory*`.  The requirements for a ridiculous number of overrides of the method/free function, or the template hackery required to have ti happen automatically, isn't worth it.